# 3D Touch Capability Check Issue - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, 3dtouch

Strange issue, I am using the standard check to see if the device has 3D Touch. It is wrapped with iOS9 check, which is passing, but not passing the `.Available` `if statement` on my iPhone 6S, which is running iOS9.1 and has 3D Touch enabled in Settings.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
     if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
          registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: view)
          constantChange = cstInfoBar.constant + 20
     }
}
```

I have set a breakpoint and I am receiving the following:

```
(lldb) po traitCollection.forceTouchCapability
error: <EXPR>:1:17: error: 'forceTouchCapability' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer
traitCollection.forceTouchCapability
                ^
<EXPR>:1:17: note: add 'if #available' version check
traitCollection.forceTouchCapability
                ^
<EXPR>:1:17: note: add @available attribute to enclosing instance method
traitCollection.forceTouchCapability
                ^
<EXPR>:1:17: note: add @available attribute to enclosing extension
traitCollection.forceTouchCapability
                ^
<EXPR>:9:9: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
    var $__lldb_error_result = __lldb_tmp_error
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: view)` works outside of the `if statement` but not a good option to implement!

**FURTHER INVESTIGATIONS**

I tested the code in my MainViewController and it worked perfectly. This is an odd situation, I have found a work around for the moment.

Comment: What does "but not going into my statement" mean?

Comment: Update question, it's been a late night of coding!

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. I tested your code and it goes thru the availability check, does the `traitCollection.forceTouchCapability` test, and fails that test in good order (because I don't have force touch).

Comment: Yeah if you don't have a 3D Touch device that is fine, the issue is that I do. I have a iPhone 6S. This is why I am baffled that this issue is happening.

Comment: So all you proved is that the view controller (is that what `self` is?) reports doesn't report `.Available`. What does the screen report? Instead of testing against `.Available`, see what it actually _is_.

Comment: I have tried both `UIForceTouchCapability.Available` and `.Available`, neither are working for me. And as per the error printed, it's telling me it's only available in iOS9 when that's what's installed on the device.

Comment: That's the part I'm really asking about. I can't reproduce any error about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95096/discussion-between-zappidev-and-matt).

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hey @JimmyB I fixed it by setting a global variable, and checking during app loading!

Comment: Hey @RichAppz! I found that my checks were in viewDidLoad, which doesn't yet have traitCollection information. I deferred my check and logic until viewDidLayoutSubviews (or similar) and it works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: I was doing this check in `viewDidLoad`, which is before the object has `traitCollection` information. Deferring checks and logic until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks JimmyB when I get the chance I will check